# Bounding the residual of Chebyshev approximations of the Heaviside function

Tags: approximation-theory, online-resources, chebyshev-polynomials

I'm looking for a resource to find bounds for Chebyshev polynomial approximations of a given degree for the Heaviside function
$$
H(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x>0,\\
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$

I've done some Googling, but I can't seem to find a good resource on this. Although at the moment, my focus is on getting bounds to approximating this function with polynomials, I know I will wish to study this for other functions as well. Is there a good place to look in general to find the order of convergence of the Chebyshev polynomials for common functions?

Put more concretely, if I have a linear combination of $k$ Chebyshev polynomials
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{l=0}^{k-1} c_lT_l(x)
\end{equation}
what can I say about
\begin{equation}
\epsilon = \int_{-1}^1 |f(x) - H(x)|dx?
\end{equation}
Is $\epsilon = $ $O(1/d)$, or $O(1/\text{poly(d)})$, or $O(1/2^d)$?

Comment: One standard book is "Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice".  ( https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/ATAP/ ).  The first 6 chapters are available online, as are matlab exercises using the "chebfun" library ( https://chebfun.org ).  Howevver, most of the results are about not just continuous, but Lipschitz continuous functions.  Chapter 9 does cover the Gibbs phenomenon with the sign function (a simple transform of Heaviside).  However almost everything is done in either the infinity-norm or the 2-norm, rather than the 1-norm that you care about.